# How do I hide button text with CSS?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to hide the text `Following` when a user hovers over a button.  I don't really have too much experience with CSS and am having difficulties doing this.

This is my button

```
<span>
   <%= link_to  'Following', follow_url(found), method: :delete, 
                class: "btn unfollow-button", id: 'unfollow-button', 
                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } 
    %>
</span>
```

Below is the application.scss

```
.unfollow-button {
  width: 100px; /* set a width so it doesnt change upon hover */
  content: 'Following';
  border-color: #bd2b2b;
  background-color: #140d6d;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 20px;
  &:visited, &:focus, &:hover {
    content: 'Following';
    border-color: #FF0000;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    color: white;
  }
```

```
  
}
.unfollow-button:hover span {
  display:none
}
.unfollow-button:hover:before {
  content:" Unfollow ";
}
```

Right now the button is appending the new content `Unfollow` to the front of the button, but not removing the old content

So the button goes from `Following` to `Unfollow Following` instead of the desired result of `Following` to `UnFollow`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<div class="item">
       <%= link_to  follow_url(found), method: :delete, 
                class: "btn unfollow-button", id: 'unfollow-button', 
                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } 
    do %>
         <p class="label success new-label"><span class="align">Following</span></p>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

in your css

```
 item{
        width: 30px;
    }
    a{
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .label {
        width: 100px; /* set a width so it doesnt change upon hover */
      content: 'Following';
      border-color: #bd2b2b;
      background-color: #140d6d;
      color: white;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }


    .item a p.new-label span{
      position: relative;
      content: 'Following'
    }
    .item:hover a p.new-label span{
      display: none;
    }
    .item:hover a p.new-label:after{
      content: 'Unfollow';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If text is not matching on hover, just swap the text in `data-follow/unfollow`

```css
.btn.unfollow-button span:hover:before {
  content: attr(data-unfollow);
}

[data-unfollow]:before {
  content: attr(data-unfollow);
}

[data-follow]:before {
  content: attr(data-follow);
}
```

```html
<!-- Rails-html should generate line below: -->
<a class="btn unfollow-button", id='unfollow-button'>
  <span data-unfollow="Unfollow" data-follow="Follow"></span>
<a />
```

```
#rails-html

<span>
 <%= link_to follow_url(found), method: :delete, 
      class: "btn unfollow-button", id: 'unfollow-button', 
      data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
      <span data-unfollow="Unfollow" data-follow="Follow"></span>
 <% end %>
<span/>
```